# Forloop with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, loops, tikz-cd

I am trying to write a macro that (for now) takes as input a number n, and outputs a tikz-cd diagram consisting of n consecutive arrows.

However the following code leads to an error:

> You can't use `\relax' after \the.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, cd, positioning}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcommand{\smallcube}[1]{%
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, nodes in empty cells]%
\newcounter{width}%
\forloop{width}{1}{\value{ct} < #1}{\ar[r]\&}\\%
\end{tikzcd}}

\begin{document}
\smallcube{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using `\foreach`?

Comment: I am quite new to Latex macros so I was not aware of `\foreach`. I  just tried it though and I still get an error. I just tried it though, using `\foreach \width in {1,...,#1} {\ar[r] \& }\\%` and I still get an error, though a different one: `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should accumulate the partial arrows; using `\foreach` is simpler:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\smallcube}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    \gdef\partialcube{}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1} {
      \gappto\partialcube{ {} \arrow[r] \& }
    }
  \partialcube {}
  \end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}
\smallcube{2}

\smallcube{4}

\smallcube{5}
\end{document}
```

Alternative method using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% get a user level version of \prg_replicate:nn
\cs_set_eq:NN \replicate \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\smallcube}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  \replicate{#1}{ {} \arrow[r] \& } {}
  \end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}
\smallcube{2}

\smallcube{4}

\smallcube{5}
\end{document}
```

[image]